# Limit Javascript file to only be used in one page (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using a javascript file named `text_messages.js` i would like this to only be used in my `text_messages\new.html.erb` page.

Right now when i get in any other page in my project in my console I get the error:

[image: error]

this error is happening because I am running the `text_messages.js` in every page which is what i am trying to prevent. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `stub` to tell Rails what's the file you don't want load despite using `require_tree .`.

For instance if your file `text_message.js` is in the `app/assets/javascripts` folder, then you can add the stub to your `application.js` file like:

```
...
//= require_tree .
//= stub 'text_message'
```

Then add your file to the precompile assets in your `config/initializers/assets.rb`, like:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( text_message.js )
```

And then add it manually to your `new.html.erb`:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'text_message' %>
```

You need to restart your server with every change in the assets file.

Comment: This was awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to assets.rb

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(path/to/text_messages.js)`

Remove the entry for this file from `application.js`

Now include this file on `text_messages\new.html.erb` page

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'path_to_text_messages.js' %>`

Restart you server

Answer (score 1):

So I think there are a few ways of doing this. you can put the javascript inline on the page and it will only be loaded there, or you can put a link to that javascript file on that page specifically. but if you put it in your assets folder I believe it will be loaded by all pages. I think the other solutions are the proper way of doing it though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! do you have any example code you can share? @

Comment: well for example you can just put this on any page

<script>
alert("hello world")
</script>

I must warn you, that even though this will work. its really lazy and i think if you are working with other rails developers they might get annoyed by the solution. but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way would be to just add the script to the html of the page you need it on, but that's probably a bad idea.

You likely want a more comprehensive solution:

There is a very good answer to this at http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/page-specific-javascript-in-rails/.

Basically, you want to open your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb and convince it to give you controller and view information each time it renders a page. Then you can use that information to  load page or controller specific scripts.To do so you change the body tag in application.html.erb from

```
<body> 
  <%= yield %>
</body>
```

to

```
<body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">
  <%= yield %>
</body>
```

So, when rails renders the body tag it will now add a class for the controller and one of the actions in the controller.

Say you have a controller called static_pages, and the static_pages controller has home defined in the controller and a view in the views. Controller will have this:

```
def home 
end
```

When rails renders the view/page home.html.erb it will now add to the body tag a class of static_pages and a class of home.

```
<body class="static_pages home">
    the home view is rendered here
</body>
```

This will be a site wide change, so if you go to an index page/view from the users controller the body tag would be:

```
<body class="users index">
    the index view is rendered here
</body>
```

Now, make a file called vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery-readyselector.js containing:

```
(function ($) {
  var ready = $.fn.ready;
  $.fn.ready = function (fn) {
    if (this.context === undefined) {
      // The $().ready(fn) case.
      ready(fn);
    } else if (this.selector) {
      ready($.proxy(function(){
        $(this.selector, this.context).each(fn);
      }, this));
    } else {
      ready($.proxy(function(){
        $(this).each(fn);
      }, this));
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

That file must be properly referenced in application.js

```
...
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery-readyselector
//= require_tree .
```

Once all that is done you can test it by making a simple alert specific to the view you want test like so:

```
// app/assets/javascripts/static_pages_home.js

$(".static_pages.home").ready(function() {
  return alert("You should only see this on the static pages home page.");
});


// app/assets/javascripts/user_index.js

$(".users.index").ready(function() {
  return alert("You should only see this on the users index page.");
});
```

You could also make a script controller specific by not referencing the action/view, only the controller.

```
$(".users").ready(function() {
  return alert("You should only see this on a users controller controlled page.");
});
```